# How to animate text for 2D animation?

Tags: animation, text-object

How do I animate text in a 2D animation? I would like to play around with text alpha (opacity), scaling the size and position. In my animation, I will use text as title and main points for my video. Can I directly animate the text object or  must I change into other types of object before animate it?

When text opacity is 0:

[image: the first image is when my text opacity=0]

When text opacity is 1:

[image: the second image is when my text opacity=1]

Basically, I just want the text to appear at a particular frame (keyframe) and hide it after a period of time.

Comment: everything is possible, it can simply be an image texture with a transparent background as you seem to say, but what kind of animations are you talking about?

Comment: edited: basically, i just want the text to appear at a particular frame(keyframe) and hide it after a period of time. btw, i just use blend mode to change the opacity of the text. is there any other way to change it opacity the same way we change (transform) it size?

Comment: so if you want it to gradually appear you can use the factor of a Mix Shader in order to switch from a Transparent shader to your Image Texture. If it appears from a frame to another you can just keyframe its visibility in the Outliner.

Comment: alright thank you sir for your favour :). I will try to play around with the Mix Shader later.

Comment: You can also use Map Range nodes in your Node Tree, which gives you more flexibility, because they can be modified by other nodes. https://youtu.be/Fh9kB2zCtnU